# Some videos causing android media player to crash

Tags: android, file, video, format, media-player

While testing an app that I was making to play videos in a loop from a playlist using the MediaPlayer, I found that one video caused my app to freeze. It didn't force close or anything just froze. After I took the video out it ran fine. But the video didn't cause it to crash every time. I was stability testing the app and it would run for at least 5 hours so it played the video a number of times before freezing. After I took out the video and put in different ones it worked fine (some were bigger and I added more than one). All the videos I was testing were mp4's and there was nothing noticeably different about the one that was crashing.

Any ideas why the video was causing the crash? It's not a huge issue but it would be nice to know so I could maybe check for it before adding a video to a playlist.

Comment: Did you encode all the videos the same way?

Comment: I didn't encode them they were all just random stock clips. Is there a way to check the encoding of a video?